# How do I reshape a non-quadratic matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a column vector `A` with dimensions (35064x1) that I want to reshape into a matrix with 720 lines and as many columns as it needs.

In MATLAB, it'd be something like this:

```
B = reshape(A,720,[])
```

in which `B` is my new matrix.

However, if I divide 35604 by 720, there'll be a remainder.

Ideally, MATLAB would go about filling every column with 720 values until the last column, which wouldn't have 720 values; rather, 504 values (48x720+504 = 35064).

Is there any function, as `reshape`, that would perform this task?

Since I am not good at coding, I'd resort to built-in functions first before going into programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reshape` preserves the number of elements but you achieve the same in two steps

```
b=zeros(720*ceil(35604/720),1); b(1:35604)=a;
reshape(b,720,[])
```

Comment: Right idea, but incorrect code. `zero(4)` creates a 4x4 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = rand(35064,1);
NoCols = 720;
tmp = mod(numel(A),NoCols ); % get the remainder
tmp2 = NoCols -tmp;
B = reshape([A; nan(tmp2,1)],720,[]); % reshape the extended column
```

This first gets the remainder after division, and then subtract that from the number of columns to find the amount of missing values. Then create an array with `nan` (or zeros, whichever suits your purpose best) to pad the original and then `reshape`. One liner:

```
A = rand(35064,1);
NoCols = 720;
B = reshape([A; nan(NoCols-mod(numel(A),NoCols);,1)],720,[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

karakfa got the right idea, but some error in his code.

Fixing the errors and slightly simplifying it, you end up with:

```
B=nan(720,ceil(numel(a)/720));
B(1:numel(A))=A;
```

Create a matrix where A fits in and assingn the elemnent of A to the first numel(A) elements of the matrix.

An alternative implementation which is probably a bit faster but manipulates your variable `b`

```
%pads zeros at the end
A(720*ceil(numel(A)/720))=0;
%reshape
B=reshape(A,720,[]);
```